# Cannot connect to apple id using Virtual Box Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-highsierra

When I try connecting to the app store, itunes, etc. it returns an error that says "Unexpected error occured". That's it, nothing else.

I have a virtual machine running Mac OS High Sierra. I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. I have given my mac environment a "serial number" using **VBoxManage setextradata “MacOS High Sierra” VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial** "number" When I go to Apple>About this Mac it lists the correct serial number I assigned it too. Before hand, it would just list the serial number as 0.

My question is, how do I connect my mac environment to my apple id for app store, itunes, etc?

Comment: Did you check console to see if it provides more information? The rest of your question would appear to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: have you solved in some way the issue? I'm trying to register on the app store from a virtual High Sierra OS

Comment: @Giox I couldn’t figure out a solution using Virtual box. I switched to VMWare and that is working for me so far.